# A more efficient way to write database CRUD operations in Android

Tags: java, android, crud, dao

I've just started learning Android development and I found out a very nice way to write models, DAOs and schema in my application. For example, I have an `Category` model where it will contain all the fields representing the columns of its table in the database:

```
public class Category {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String createdAt;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

The `CategoryDao` class will then be responsive for accessing the database and performing all the operations:

```
package com.prettypenny.dao;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import com.prettypenny.model.Category;
import com.prettypenny.schema.CategorySchema;
import com.prettypenny.schema.DatabaseHandler;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Category D.A.O
 */
public class CategoryDao {
    SQLiteOpenHelper helper;
    SQLiteDatabase database;

    private static final String[] columns = {
        CategorySchema.COL_ID,
        CategorySchema.COL_NAME,
        CategorySchema.COL_CREATED_AT,
    };

    public CategoryDao(Context context) {
        helper = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    }

    public void open() {
        database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        helper.close();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve all Category
     * @return ArrayList
     */
    public ArrayList<Category> all() {
        Cursor cursor = database.query(CategorySchema.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

        ArrayList<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();

        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                Category category = new Category();
                category.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(CategorySchema.COL_ID)));
                category.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CategorySchema.COL_NAME)));

                categories.add(category);
            }
        }

        return categories;
    }

    /**
     * Inserts a new Category
     * @param category Category category to be inserted
     * @return Category
     */
    public Category insert(Category category) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CategorySchema.COL_NAME, category.getName());

        database.insert(CategorySchema.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

        return category;
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing Category
     * @param category Category category to be updated
     * @return int
     */
    public int update(Category category) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CategorySchema.COL_NAME, category.getName());

        return database.update(
            CategorySchema.TABLE_NAME,
            values,
            CategorySchema.COL_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(category.getId()) }
        );
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing Category
     * @param id int id of the category to be deleted
     */
    public void delete(int id) {
        database.delete(
            CategorySchema.TABLE_NAME,
            CategorySchema.COL_ID + " = " + id,
            null
        );
    }
}
```

But as I create more and more entities in my application, I feel bothered to have to type all these same things, so I thought of doing an abstract class `Dao` that will have all these operations and the classes would just extend it.

```
abstract class Dao {
    SQLiteOpenHelper helper;
    SQLiteDatabase database;

    public ArrayList<?> all(String tableName, String[] columns) {
        Cursor cursor = database.query(tableName, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

        ArrayList<?> entities = new ArrayList<>();

        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                // Oh shit.
            }
        }

        return entities;
    }
}
```

The problem now, for example, in the `all()` method is the model class to be instantiated, as in the `CategoryDao.all()` instantiates `Category`. Is it possible to be achieved within the abstract class, say, doing something similar like `ArrayList<?>` does, where it passes something that might be of any type?

Comment: Would it be an option to use some ORM, or even another database that facilitates implementation? I have some suggestions.

Comment: I never thought of using an ORM, actually didn't know there was. But I actually would like to know about my question, if that'd be possible and also, for me to learn Java more.

Comment: ORM is Object Relational Mapping. They are libraries that facilitate the management of entities as objects. For Java EE the most popular is Hibernate.

Comment: search about android ROOM

Comment: if you don't want to use ORM u can do this with reflection, and i think this is how ORM work, so you will be re-inventing the wheel, but as experimentation it could be a good exercise

Comment: Yes, the main issue would be for me to learn more, @Yazan.

Comment: go ahead then , there is plenty of resources about reflection, and if you face specific issue, ask about it.

Answer (score 1):

One of the biggest challenges when working with databases in any language is relational mapping between the database tables and entity objects.

Thinking about it, are created libraries/frameworks called ORM (Object Relational Mapping).

My first suggestion is to use [Realm Database](http://realm.io), but since you already work with SQLite, my list is:

- Sugar ORM: http://satyan.github.io/sugar/
- ORM Lite: http://ormlite.com/android/examples/
- Green DAO: http://greenrobot.org/greendao/
- Active Android: http://www.activeandroid.com/
- Android Room: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html (suggested by Sajad Garshasbi)

A comparison between them can be found [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/5-best-android-orms/) and [here](http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/a-comparison-of-android-orms).

Comment: Alright, there are many alternatives. I wanted to implement my idea with reflections, to understand more the Java language itself. Thank you.

Comment: Be careful with reflection on Android. Reflection is slow and costly. Normally, in Android, the ORMs use code generation to avoid the use of reflection. Good luck in your studies.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you take a look at Google's room approach. It's still not stable and you'll need android studio 3.0 which is still not stable, but I haven't noticed any issues with any of those.

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-persistence/#0

It has very interesting advantages over the typical alternatives, one of which is checking that your SQL statements match your db at compile time. I'm not aware of anyone else offering this particular feature.